# Laravel Eloquent - Mapping an array based on a relationship field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Projects model, that can have multiple ProjectUsers, which each have multiple Schedule models. The Schedule models save the amount of planned and actual hours worked by the ProjectUser per week. The models look as follows:

```
Project:
 - name
 - start_date
 - end_date
 - status

ProjectUser:
 - project_id
 - designation_id
 - user_id

Schedule:
 - project_user_id (this ties the Schedule to a ProjectUser)
 - week_id (this ties the Schedule to a Week)
 - planned_hours
 - actual_hours

Week:
 - month (int)
 - year (int)
 - week_start_date
```

What I want to do, is to return an array that sums the amount of planned hours per month for the next 12 months for each project status. So it would look like this:

```
[
  0 => [               // this represents the current month
    'status_1': 123,
    'status_2': 234,
    ...
  ],
  1 => [              // this represents next month
    'status_1': 321,
    'status_2': 222,
    ...
  ],
  ...
]
```

This would mean that I need to potentially do a map considering a relationship field (as I'm looking to group planned_hours by the month and year on the Week model).

I've tried this a few times without success, can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you set up your relationships correctly? Is it a one to many relationship from ProjectUser to Project?

Comment: One to many. One project has many project users. I got this to work but the code is messy. There must be an elegant way to do this.